# How to use cjk on miktex

Tags: cjk

On the forum are a lot of questions about `cjk`, by using them I managed to build the code for typing japanese (The fonts `T8K`,`T8M` are for georgian and may be changed)

```
\documentclass[8pt]{article}
\input{glyphtounicode} 
\pdfgentounicode=1 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage[T8K,T8M]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[thaicjk,english,georgian]{babel}
\addto\extrasthaicjk{\fontencoding{C90}\selectfont}
\makeatletter
\@namedef{opt@inputenc.sty}{utf8}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}

あ い　え　う　

\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately it works only on texlive (linux), and wasn't able to build working one for miktex (windows). I installed from "package manager (admin)" `cjk` and `cjk-fonts`, but pdflatex doesn't compile it.

How to write working code? (I need it to be compiled by `pdflatex`)

Comment: Quite a number of cjk fonts are missing in miktex. You must install them manually. See e.g. https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2095/